# nginx included file not relaoding properly

Tags: php, linux, nginx, azure-linux

I am using Linux azure box for PHP application. In my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file I have added one file containing set of redirections. See code below,

```
include /home/site/nginx_redirections.txt;
```

And nginx_redirections.txt contains content like below(more than 500 redirections),

```
location /one {
   return 301 https:example.com/oneredirect.html;
}
location /two {
  return 301  https:example.com/tworedirect.html;
}
```

nginx_redirections.txt will change once in every month. But after changing new redirections are not reflecting. I am getting file not found error even after reloading nginx.

Can someone help me to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you restart nginx after changing the file?

Comment: Yes, I tried restart , reload and stop the server and start. Nothing works. It only reads old file. New changes are not reflecting.